# Edgecolor not appearing on Seaborn stripplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, stripplot

Following the example on the Seaborn API site and I can't seem to get the edgecolor to appear

Here's what I'm using

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, size=4, jitter=True, edgecolor="gray")
```

but this is the is what's being plotted. Am I missing something? I'm using Seaborn .6 and Matplotlib 1.4.3 with Python 3
[image: MatplotlibPlot]

[Seaborn Boxplot API](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A `linewidth` greater than 0 must be added to [`seaborn.stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html), for the edgecolor (`ec`) to show.

  - `lw` will not result in an error, but the edgecolor will not display if `lw` is used for `linewidth`.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.3`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns

# load dataframe
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)

# add stripplot with linewidth=1
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, size=4, jitter=True,
              edgecolor="gray", ax=ax, linewidth=1)
```

[image]